# C# JSon Deserialize Object using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net, json-deserialization

The Json File looks like,

```
{
    "cat": {    
        "colour":"brown",
        "height": "30cm"
    },
    "dog" {
        "colour":"brown"
    }
}
```

So I created a classes as

```
public class DataModel{
public class root
{
public Cat cats{get;set}
public Dog dogs{get;set}
}
public class Cat{
public string colour {get; set;}
public string height {get; set;}
}
public class Dog{
public string colour {get; set;}
}
```

How to Deserialize  this using Newtonsoft.Json in C#.

I tried Creating classes, but couldnnt get it done.

Comment: What code are you using to deserialize the string? How didn't it work?

Comment: Just use `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileContent)` for this.

Comment: @Essigwurst I'd avoid dynamic, it defeats the point of a strongly typed language. At least use `JToken.Parse()` if you don't want to make the classes, that's LINQ compatible.

Comment: Please format your JSON when you ask a question and please describe what failed. I just formatted your JSON and it's _quite obvious_ that you have a typo (you are missing a colon (`:`) after `"dog"`

Comment: You've named the properties on the C# class `cats` and `dogs`, but they each only contain a single Cat and Dog. Is this intentional?

Comment: Any reason to use nested classes?? Did you try to move the root, cat and doc classes out of the DataModel class?

Comment: You need to modify the object model slightly so that the property names should match the JSON

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `root` object model slightly, the property names should match the JSON, or use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

e.g.

```
public class root
{
  public Cat Cat {get;set;}
  public Dog Dog {get;set;}
}
```

or using `[JsonProperty]`

```
public class root
{
  [JsonProperty("cat")] public Cat cats {get;set;}
  [JsonProperty("dog")] public Dog dogs {get;set;}
}
```

Then use the generic `DeserializeObject` e.g.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(jsonContent);
```